# Is "x/2" and "x*0.5" different in C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

When I'm working on showing chart in QML, I found an interested things:

```
# Run this code

for(int col = 1; col <= 5; col ++){
    qDebug() << col;
    qDebug() << col/2;
    qDebug() << col*0.5;
}


# Output
1
0
0.5

2
1
1

3
1
1.5

4
2
2

5
2
2.5
```

Though the problem has been solved, I'm still wondering:
**"Why the output did not do implicit casting to convert the int to float?"**

Thanks a lot for your great help!

Comment: a/b is integer division if both are integers, and floating point division if any of them is float/double.

Comment: Yes /2 = integer division. *.5 is a floating point multiplication (makes the result a double).
To make a floating point division  use /2.0;

Comment: "Why the output did not do implicit casting to convert the int to float?"" Even if it did, `2` converted to a float is `2.0` not `2.5`

Comment: Which one do you consider to be "the int" that you expected to be converted?

Comment: _"..."Why the output did not do implicit casting to convert the int to float?"..."_ what if the end-user wanted integer division?